# How to store Persian characters using Json field in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I tried to store Persian characters with Jsonfield, but I had the following problem when displaying characters in the database.

```
"{'\u0628\u0631\u0646\u062f}"
```

models:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class example(models.Model):
spec_json = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaZnv.png)

Comment: Did you set the field of table to use correct data type such as utf-?

Comment: Yes, the other storage field, like arrayfield, stores without problems. The only field that causes a problem is this field.